# Changing Angular Material Form Field Appearance dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a form which uses material form fields. Based on the **appearance** config provided to the application, I plan to switch between **outline and fill** appearances.

I was trying to bind respective appearance to the **mat-form-field** as below:

```
<mat-form-field [appearance]="getAppearance()"> some mat-label & mat-input </mat-form-field>
```

When I try to use this, I was able to console log the appearance inside **getApperance()** method. However, the page doesn't render any of the fields. Not sure, why the property binding to appearance is not working.

I found a link: https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/angular-material-form-field-appearance/ . But this is not helpful as it is not setting the appearance dynamically.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oe7ysu-mffz7l) I have tried Its working!

Comment: Thanks Sameer, its working.